# How to align the text position in flutter

Tags: flutter

Can anyone explain me how to align the text in the flutter code? My output looks messy and did not look good.

[image]

this is the code part for the output

[image]

Comment: how do you want it aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use crossAxisAlignment and mainAxisAlignment to define the position of the children...

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,

  children: <Widget>[
    Text('We move under cover and we move as one'),
    Text('Through the night, we have one shot to live another day'),
    Text('We cannot let a stray gunshot give us away'),
    Text('We will fight up close, seize the moment and stay in it'),
    Text('It’s either that or meet the business end of a bayonet'),
    Text('The code word is ‘Rochambeau,’ dig me?'),
    
  ],
)
```

Comment: thank you, it is working for me. For a beginner like me, should be noted that mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, is inside Column/Row.

Answer (score 1):

```
child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, //To align at start
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, //To align at end
      children: [

      ],
    );
)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.